# How to get x11vnc to run at startup on openSuSE 12.1

Tags: linux, boot, vnc, xorg, opensuse

I'm trying to get x11vnc to run at startup with openSuse but not having much luck.  Here's what I did so far.

I edited `/etc/X11/xdm/Xsetup` and added the following lines to the end, right before `exit 0`:

```
#run x11vnc automatically
/usr/bin/x11vnc -rfbauth /usr/bin/vnc/passwd -o /var/log/x11vnc.log -forever -bg
```

I created the `/usr/bin/vnc/passwd file using:

```
sudo x11vnc -storepasswd /usr/bin/vnc/passwd
```

When I reboot, I do a `ps -A | grep x11` and do not see the process running.  I also see no `/var/log/x11vnc.log` file created.  I can run the command from bash directory and it works fine.  I have a feeling this script is never getting run at startup.

I also created a new file called `/etc/kde4/kdm/Xsetup` and put the two lines from above in there, and same behavior.

The file permissions are:

```
-rw------- 1 root root 8 Apr 26 22:26 /usr/bin/vnc/passwd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5691 Apr 26 22:01 /etc/X11/xdm/Xsetup
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I've even tried just echo'ing *Hello World* to a text file in `Xsetup` which also does nothing.  It seems this script simply doesn't get run at boot.

**UPDATE 2:**

I upgraded to 12.1, however none of my attempts have worked either.

Comment: i have a few questions if you dont mind: 1. what display manager are u running (KDM or GDM) 2. is there a particular reason for preference to x11vnc over the default vnc server of your distribution 3. best i know, vnc allows you to share a desktop after login and not the login session itself, is that sufficient for you... thanks...

Comment: @user1055604 - 1) I'm running KDE. 2) No, x11vnc is just the first one I looked up how to install and get working but I'm fine with any VNC server really and 3) Yes, automatically starting after a logon is fine as well.

Comment: thanks... check out my post... hope it solves your problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I could find, either should work:

---

### To fix x11vnc:

Enter these commands at a console as the `user`:

```
mkdir ~/.vnc
x11vnc -storepasswd "password" ~/.vnc/passwd
```

Put this in the ~/.x11vncrc file replacing `user` with your username:

```
display :0
rfbauth /home/user/.vnc/passwd
forever
bg
```

Now to autostart it each time the `user` logs in:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/x11vnc ~/.kde/Autostart/x11vnc
```

Now reboot or restart the desktop session.

([src](http://rivendell.tryphon.org/wiki/Remote_Administration_with_VNC#Generic_Configuration_using_x11vnc_with_KDE))

---

### YaST:

> From the KDE desktop, select the YaST icon, enter the root password, and select OK; then select *Network Services > Remote Administration*.
>
> Select Allow Remote Administration; then select Finish

([src](http://ocw.novell.com/suse-linux-enterprise-server-administrators/suse-linux-administration/3037_10_manual.pdf))

Comment: This looks promising, I will try this later on today!

Comment: Tried both, neither work..  I did notice `Autostart` didn't exist, so I created it first. But x11vnc does not start at logon.  `Allow Remote Administration` was already on this whole time, however it has no effect.  Still can't VNC into the box.  Thanks for trying though!

Comment: Ok I have no idea why this doesn't work, all the docs say it will.  However, the `.x11vncrc` file seemed to help a lot.  I found a method involving creating a file in `~/.config/autostart` which finally works combined with your first step.  I think this answer is probably the best out of the bunch though.  Thanks!

Comment: `.config/autostart` is the new place where both KDE and Gnome look for their autostart files, in the `.desktop` format... the src i used was really old... good to know it worked out...

Answer (score 3):

Revert `/etc/X11/xdm/Xsetup` back to it's original state (remove your edits). This is not being called during system boot.

Add your startup line `/usr/bin/x11vnc -rfbauth /usr/bin/vnc/passwd -o /var/log/x11vnc.log -forever -bg` to the file `/etc/init.d/after.local`.

Unless you want write a compliant `init script` that starts/stops/restarts the `x11vnc` process (which is possible but beyond the scope of this answer), you should place any processes you want to execute on boot in `/etc/init.d/after.local`.

Note: On RedHat systems, this would go in `rc.local`. SUSE uses `before.local` (execute before the init scripts) and `after.local` (execute after the init scripts).

Comment: This will start it as the system boots, not when KDE starts.

Comment: This doesn't work. x11nvc still isn't running at boot and if I look in the logs I see: `*** x11vnc was unable to open the X DISPLAY: ":0", it cannot continue.` - I'm gonna guess because there's not yet a valid display to bind to when `after.local` gets run?

Comment: Full log: http://pastie.org/3851743

Comment: For clarification, X *is* running on this host, right? You have a graphical login screen and desktop?

Comment: @uther - Yes, default openSuse 12.1 install with a KDE desktop..  Nothing too special about it..

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a SuSE 11 install in front of me to check.

Uther's on the right track - but you need to get the program to start AFTER X11 has been started.

I don't know for sure if it CAN work if just X is running - would you WANT it to be run if, for example, "guest" logged in via the X-window login screen?

With 12, SuSE changes all of the startup script stuff, so you may just want to upgrade, then fix it on 12:

http://news.opensuse.org/2011/12/22/systemd-%E2%80%93-boot-faster-and-cleaner-with-opensuse-12-1/

As a general goal, you'll want to figure out what's actually running as your "login screen" under X (probably gdm - http://projects.gnome.org/gdm/ ) and how that got fired up.  Wherever it's getting run, you'll want to run your x11vnc either directly before or directly after that.

Comment: Thanks!  I've upgraded to 12 (I was meaning to anyway), but still I can't seem to find a script that actually gets run after X starts..

Comment: I don't think you'll find one.   You'll want to chase the scripts that are STARTING X - look for whatever's running GDM.  Once you find it, you can either (a) call your script and be done, or (b) code a generic "hook" that runs some after-x-starts.sh script if it exists, and submit that change back to the project.